# Issue with mysqli_query in PHP - query works in phpmyadmin and not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run an insert query using PHP. As mentioned in the title it works in phpmyadmin but does not work in php code.

**Below is the code:**

```
if ($result) {

  session_start();
  $_SESSION['fname'] = $firstname;
  $firstname_sess = $_SESSION['fname'];
  $sql_uid = " SELECT id FROM users WHERE firstname = '" . $firstname_sess . "' ";
  var_dump($sql_uid);
  $sql_uid_result = mysqli_query($db, $sql_uid);
  $sql_uid_array = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_uid_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  $sql_uid_final = $sql_uid_array['id'];
  var_dump($sql_uid_final);
  mysqli_query('SET foreign_key_checks = 0');
  $uo_uid = "INSERT INTO `user_order` (user_id) VALUES ('$sql_uid_final')";
  var_dump($uo_uid);
  $uo_uid_final = mysqli_query($db, $uo_uid);
  var_dump($uo_uid_final);
  if ($uo_uid_final) {

    echo "All good";
  } else {
    echo "Something went wrong 1";
  }
  //header('Location: productsform.php');

} else {
  echo "Somethingwentwrong2";
}
```

**Code Explanation:**

1. There are two tables users and user_order
2. Trying to fetch existing user's user id from users table to user_order table.
3. user_order table has user_id as a foreign key referencing id(PK) field  in users table.
4. Facing issue while inserting the value in user_order table.

**Although the code works through PHP myadmin or terminal but is not working via PHP code.**

I have gone through the similar links given below:
1. [mysql DELETE works on phpmyadmin but not on php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983118/mysql-delete-works-on-phpmyadmin-but-not-on-php-script)
2. [SQL query working in phpmyadmin but not in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34840808/sql-query-working-in-phpmyadmin-but-not-in-php)
3. [mysqli_query works in phpmyadmin but not in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40962002/mysqli-query-works-in-phpmyadmin-but-not-in-php)
4. [Query works in phpMyAdmin but not in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500927/query-works-in-phpmyadmin-but-not-in-php)

And many more but could not find anything. Any help would really be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I see in your code is this line:

```
mysqli_query('SET foreign_key_checks = 0');
```

You haven't provided $db as the first argument of mysqli_query.

If that's not the issue, could you provide the mylsqli_error() for the query that fails?

Comment: Hi @Michael Beeson $db as the first argument, worked. Thank you for the quick support. 

Also when I tried mysqli_error() below was the error description:

Error description: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cafepoc`.`user_order`, CONSTRAINT `user_order_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))

which clearly mentions there has been something wrong with the foreign_key_check mysqli_query.

Once again thank you for the response.

Comment: Glad it helped! Accept the answer to give me that juicy kudos!